# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars in python pandas using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, pandas-styles

I have used `styler.background_gradient` with seaborn colors and it worked perfectly until i run with different data. Now i have different data set which have some missing data, or weird combinations, so I get some results that have infinite values or something not quite right, but still I need that data, but colors are having hard time. How do I avoid this in picture.

[image]

This is what I see when I export data to excel and I get this error in terminal.

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  norm = colors.Normalize(smin - (rng * low), smax + (rng * high))
```

How to avoid this?

this is code

```
    cr = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)

    styler = output.style  # Keep Styler for reuse
    green = styler.background_gradient(
        cmap=cr,
        subset=output.columns.get_loc_level('column_name', level=1)[0]
    )
```

Comment: I need the state of the data (infinite, multi-index) to answer this question as well. And what happens if I specify the subset as follows. `subset=[('level0', 'level1')]`

Comment: I get this because I have bad data, I have cases to do division with zero. For me would work to just exclude the inf value, but it would be a zero. subset it make no change with bad data

Comment: Then replace inf with NaN, otherwise the background will be displayed correctly.